# Onclick not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am having trouble with my onclick in IE. It works in all other browsers except for IE. Any suggestions would help. Here is my code. It is calling an xml file to show the images in an array and then the nextImage and prevImage are the buttons to click. Here is my code.

```
         function setImage(arrayPOS){
           $('#slideimage').attr('src', iArray[arrayPOS]);
           $('#slideimage').attr('alt', aArray[arrayPOS]);

           var nextPOS;
           var prevPOS;

           if (arrayPOS === num){
              nextPOS = 0;
           }
           else {
              nextPOS = arrayPOS + 1;
           }

           if (arrayPOS === 0){
              prevPOS = num;
           }

           else {
              prevPOS = arrayPOS - 1;
           }

          $('#nextImage').attr('onclick', 'setImage(' + nextPOS + ')');
          $('#prevImage').attr('onclick', 'setImage(' + prevPOS + ')');
       }
```

Comment: Why oh why do you use inline event handlers, if you already have jQuery?

Comment: `.attr('onclick'`, using `onclick` attribute with jQuery is _madness_.

Comment: Don't use `onlick`, you are using jQuery! ` $('#nextImage').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); // do you business here });`

Comment: What version of IE? Satpal's solution below should work, as jQuery works rather well cross browser. No reason to use onclick when you have the power of jQuery :)

Comment: why would you want to use obstrusive onxxxxx attributes if you already have jQuery at your hands with comprehensive event binding methods like .on() or .click() etc.?

Comment: @moonwave99 I'm glad you brought up preventDefault() as not doing so can cause all sorts of headaches that take forever to figure out ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use event handlers NOT event attributes

To allow for some flexibility (and to keep you sane) you can bind your `onclick` event handler using a selector to grab your element and `bind` to it:

```
// ...

// Get the element and bind a click event to it
$('#nextImage').click(function(){

    setImage( nextPOS );

});

// Same goes for #prevImage
```

The above method allows for a much more flexible (and cross browser) way of handling your events.